# Why the code give me only 'odd' - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time

I am creating a quiz game, when you click a button it creates a random boolean value of `0` or `1`.

This code should return a `0` or `1` depending upon if the time in seconds is equal or odd but at the moment it only gives me odd values?

```
var secounds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

if (secounds % 2 == 0){
  nia++;
}
else {
  nca++;
}
```

Comment: What are `nia` and `nca`? *What* gives you odd?

Comment: console.log(new Date().getTime() / 1000).... what do you expect to happen when you have decimal numbers....

Comment: @Shakespear The question is pretty clear as it is and shows what the OP is attempting. As you can see, the question has already been answered.

Comment: Date.now() would be better/faster/less memory using

Comment: You should first research about decimal numbers  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92451/can-decimal-numbers-be-considered-even-or-odd

Comment: @ScottMarcus. sorry for my comment, and thanks, I believe I understood 'odd result' as 'strange result' at the first look. I suggested an edit to be more clear.

Comment: for FZs : nia++ = 0 and nca++ = 1 , this code for lucky button in quiz game when you click, the code send random string (0 or 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dividing by 1000, you are getting a decimal value on most attempts and therefore the modulo remainder is not 0. Remove the `/ 1000` and you'll get evens more often.

```js
var secounds = new Date().getTime();

if (secounds % 2 == 0){
  console.log(secounds, secounds/1000, "even");
} else {
  console.log(secounds, secounds/1000, "odd");
}
```

Comment: thank you, my code in the top worked after removed " / 1000".